# Save image into my app (into fragment) from specific user in firebase database

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in android Firebase. I am trying to save an image from my Firebase database into my android app in a **fragment**.

More specificaclly, I want to search the Id of the user that is currently logged in. After I found the Id, I want to take the content of the image field (the image is a child of the user) and save it on a imageview in my app.

My main purpose is to create a profile image for the user.

This is my Firebase database:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "Tc2N9FA0uhTFZuMRNkRSHgiaGQ22" : {
      "imageurl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...
      "userid" : "Tc2N9FA0uhTFZuMRNkRSHgiaGQ22"
    }
  }
}
```

My code in the app is (I am showing only the part that I have tried to save the image):

```
public class Tab1MyProfile extends Fragment  {

ImageView userImageProfileView;


    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_my_profile, container, false);

    userImageProfileView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for(DataSnapshot userDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    userImageProfileView = userDetails.child("Name").getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


}
```

This is where my error is:

```
userImageProfileView = userDetails.child("Name").getValue());
```

The error is:
Incompatible types:
Required:android.widget.ImageView Found:java.lang.Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Users` node is a direct child of your Firebase database, to get the those values from a specific user, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userIdRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String imageurl = dataSnapshot.child("imageurl").getValue(String.class);
        String userid = dataSnapshot.child("userid").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", imageurl + " / " + userid);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com... / Tc2N9FA0uhTFZuMRNkRSHgiaGQ22
```